# PHP Form only showing name email and message in email, not the rest

Tags: php, forms, email

In my emails , I am only recieving the customer's name email and the message contents. Just wanted to see what you guys think - no clue why this is happening.
Here's my code.

```
  <form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate>
                <div class="control-group form-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <label>Full Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
                        <p class="help-block"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group form-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <label>Phone Number:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number.">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group form-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <label>Email Address:</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
                    </div>
                </div>

                  <div class="control-group form-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <label>Best way for us to reach back to you:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="reach"  required data-validation-required-message="Please enter the best way we can reach you.">
                    </div>
                </div>

                  <div class="control-group form-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <label>Type of event: (ex. sports/wedding/business) </label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="event" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your type of event.">
                    </div>
                </div>

                  <div class="control-group form-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <label>Date or Weekend Desired (ex. 4/16-4/25) </label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="date" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your desired date." >
                    </div>
                </div>

                  <div class="control-group form-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <label>Number of Attendees:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="attendees" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your number of attendees.">
                    </div>
                </div>

                  <div class="control-group form-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <label>Overnight Guests</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="overnight" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your number of overnight guests.">
                    </div>

                </div>
                  <div class="control-group form-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <label>Meals Included? (Yes/No/Maybe)</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="meals" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter whether or not you'd like meals included."> 

                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="control-group form-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <label>Additional Information:</label>
                        <textarea rows="10" cols="100" class="form-control" name="message" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your message" maxlength="3999" style="resize:none"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="success"></div>
                <!-- For success/fail messages -->
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send Message</button>
            </form>
```

That was the HTML here's the PHP.

```
    <?php
// check if fields passed are empty
if(empty($_POST['name'])        ||
   empty($_POST['phone'])       ||
   empty($_POST['email'])       ||
   empty($_POST['message']) ||
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   {
    echo "No arguments Provided!";
    return false;
   }

$name = $_POST['name'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$phone =$_Post['phone'];
$reach = $_Post['reach'];
$event = $_Post['event'];
$date = $_Post['date'];
$attendees = $_Post['attendees'];
$overnight = $_Post['overnight'];
$meals = $_Post['meals'];
$message = $_POST['message'];




$to = 'me(notmyactualemail)@gmail.com'; 
$email_subject = "Wahnee Events Inquiry"; 
$email_body = "Hooray! You have an event inquiry.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: $name \n\nPhone: $phone \n\nEmail: $email_address \n\nPhone: $phone \n\nReach: $reach \n\nEvent: $event \n\nDate: $date \n\nAttendees: $attendees \n\nOvernight: $overnight \n\nMeals: $meals \n\nInfo: $message";
$headers = "From: inquiry@wahneeevents.com\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";                                                                                                                                           
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;            
?>
```

Here's the email I get ( I put working next to anything working)

Hooray! You have an event inquiry.

Here are the details:

Name: WORKING

Phone:

Email: WORKING

Phone:

Reach:

Event:

Date:

Attendees:

Overnight:

Meals:

Info: WORKING

Thanks so much! :)

Comment: `$_POST` is not the same as ` $_Post`. PHP is case sensitive when it comes to variable names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add all your message body variables in one variable like:

```
$mesage = "Name: " . $_POST['name'];
$mesage .= $_POST['phone'];
$mesage .= $_POST['email'];
$mesage .=$_POST['phone'];
$mesage .= $_POST['reach'];
$mesage .= $_POST['event'];
$mesage .= $_POST['date'];
$mesage .= $_POST['attendees'];
$mesage .= $_POST['overnight'];
$mesage .= $_POST['meals'];
$mesage .= $_POST['message'];
```

and just pass $message in:

```
$email_body = $message;
```

Comment: That'll make for a nice, readable message...